# Setting field values on a per-import basis when using Feeds

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

A student newspaper I work with is needing some way of importing XML files from InDesign. I'm thinking [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds/)/[Feeds XPath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) is the best route for this.

However, one problem with this is that each week the Production Editor will need to import 4-8 XML files, one for each section. "Section" is a taxonomy field in the Drupal "Article" content type, and it's listed nowhere in the XML files they output.

To this end, **is there any way to manually set the values of certain fields when importing, on a per-import basis?**

I'm thinking this would look like a text box that shows up in Feeds UI when uploading the XML file. [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) seems like an idea, but it looks like it's more designed to set default values, and less set specific values on a per-import basis.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I didn't really need to do anything really differently.

Feeds XPath Parser gives you fields to change XPaths while importing. If you use the syntax:

`string('News')`

...in place of an XPath, it will assign the value ('News', in this case) as the output (Which works fine for taxonomy terms).

Answer (score 1):

There's also [hook_feeds_after_parse()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_parse/7) which lets you modify what's being saved to to your targets.  Something like this should work:

```
function my_module_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {

  if($result->title == 'title-of-feed-importer') {
    foreach($result->items as $item_key => &$item) {
      if ($item_key == "name-of-the-field") {
        $item = 'Value to set';
      }
    }
  }

}
```